# why child.stdin writable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn, node-streams

Why is Class:child_process.stdin a writable stream? How should I reason this?
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdin

---

Background:

Newbie here. Doing problem 'duplex' of nodeschool stream-adventure.

I struggled on the problem while I (wrongly) assume the interface `require('duplexer2')([Writable Stream],[Readable Stream])` should be used as `require('duplexer2')(child.stdout, child.stdin)`

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the point of view, child.stdin is readable for the child process but is writeable for any external process communicating with it (including the parent process you're writing).
Similarly, child.stdout is readable for an external process.

It's confusing, I just figured this out myself so you're in good company.